# Got Null String while get data From EditText in android

Tags: android, string, null, android-edittext

I got null data while fetch data from text Box.

My Code is:

```
EditText msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Et_Msg);
String setMsg=msg.getText().toString();
Log.v("Messge","Message::"+setMsg);
```

Please tell me where I am wrong ?

Comment: you have to move this 
`String setMsg=msg.getText().toString();` under some button click

Comment: String setMsg=msg.getText().toString(); it will work on some listener!!

Comment: I had used that on Button But it got null string

Comment: May be you did not type anything.

Comment: if the EditText is not populated or set to null in other words, you are bound to get null. Place some check.

Comment: when you need to get text form edittext?

Comment: @PoojaRoy - what was the solution and who gave the solution ? You can click the answer as accepted for that. Else you can write your solution and mark it as accepted after 2 days so that this question can be considered as resolved.

Comment: Just the problem was I wasnt wrote settext code into listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code,

```
EditText msg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Et_Msg);
String setMsg=msg.getText().toString();
Log.v("Messge","Message::"+setMsg);
```

- The first line is initializing the EditText. When it does by default there is no value ( string ) in the edittext.
- In the second line you are trying to fetch a string from a **blank edittext**, that's why it is giving you `NullPointerException`.

Solution : I suggest you to move your line `String setMsg=msg.getText().toString();` to somewhere else where you are actually going to use the value of EditText.

Answer (score 2):

While getting your data from EditText, you must `create a listener` orelse you get the value as `null` for an example button click listener..
For an example:

```
 public class A extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button btn;
    EditText edt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saved){
    super.onCreate(saved);
    edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
    if(v == btn){
    String setMsg=edt.getText().toString();
    Log.v("Messge","Message::"+setMsg);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

see.. what you are doing.. immediately after obtaining and `EditText`'s object you are calling `getText()` on it.. think logically.. obviously there is nothing (it should return blank though not sure why it is returing null) in the `EditText` unless you have it from the `xml`.. something like this;

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:text="Hey there"
    ...
/>
```

try this.. or move `getText()` call under some button click..

Answer (score 2):

Please replace your below line

```
String setMsg=msg.getText().toString();
```

with

```
String setMsg = String.valueOf(msg.getText());
```

Please try above line. Your problem will be solved.

Comment: It does same thing, the main problem is that when OP is initialize a Editext at that time it is blank, hence she is getting an error.